# How to identify churn accounts in teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

So I have created a table that has the following columns from a transaction table with all customer purchase records: 1. Month-Year, 2.Customer ID, 3. Number of Transactions in that month.

I'm trying to create a table that has the output of 1. Month-Year, 2. Number of churned customers in that month defined as customers who have not had a transaction in the last 12 month.

I would appreciate any suggestions here- I can't figure out how to quantify the date range difference. Was thinking about rank ordering and subtracting the rank order dates but that doesn't work in execution.

Comment: What if the customer came back after more than a year, is this still a churn account? E.g. no purchase between Jan 2014 and Jun 2015, should this be counted from Jan (or Feb) 2015 to May 2015?

Comment: No it's not. A customer can reactivate. So if there's no purchase between Jan 2014 and Jun 2015, the account would be counted as churn only in Feb 2015. If that person then has a transaction in March of 2015 but none until May 2016 then they've churned again in April of 2016. Thanks Dnoeth!